# Is it possible to push admin notices to one specific user instead of all users?

Tags: admin, notices

guys. I wonder if it is possible to display an admin notice to the user with the ID of, say, 3, while all other users won't receive the notice?

Comment: There are various admin notices and different ways to add custom notices. But if you're specifically referring to notices added by your code, what's your code?

Comment: Hi, Sally. Actually, I want to display an admin notice to a user on every page of the dashboard, after his posts have been updated by someone else. Using plugins isn't my option and I would like to write the code myself. I found this page for reference: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-admin-notices-in-wordpress/

Comment: Where are you planning to store the notices? At a pinch you might get away with storing them in the transients API, e.g. with key 'notices_for_<userId>', with a long lifetime. You'd need an Ajax endpoint or a page to click through to to clear these though. Just using transients you do risk that notices would be lost if updated from two different places at once, or time out, or deleted as part of some scheduled transient clean-up job, but with low volume that might be acceptable.

Comment: Which is all because I'm trying to avoid suggesting you store the notifications as a custom post type. but that probably is the best mechanism available if you need resilience and reliability. I'd still probably read them into a transient though, but you can invalidate that every time you update the posts. Unless you want to make a separate database table for them, but that's not really needed here and feels a bit yuk too. Maybe one custom post per user and messages as comments on that post?

Comment: Or there must be plugins that do user-to-user messaging: it might be worth looking at some of those for inspiration.

Comment: @GaryHu, if you're referring to actual push notifications like those on your phone when an SMS message arrives, then you might want to try an existing solution like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/onesignal-free-web-push-notifications/). But for "standard" admin notices, then you could simply hook to [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) and display the notification you want. As for limiting the visibility, something like `if ( 3 == get_current_user_id() ) { echo 'Notice for user 3'; }` would do it.

Comment: Thank you, Rup and Sally for the advice. I made use of Sally's code and that worked successfully.